# Install pymongo on macosx

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to install pymongo on my macosx. Using `python -m pip install pymongo`, I get this error message :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 732, in install
**kwargs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 835, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1030, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 344, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 315, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bson'
```

I get an other error message using easy_install

```
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-526.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or the distutils default setting) was:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment variable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not running it as root. The safest thing to do is use the "user" mode to install your requirements in your home directory.

E.g.:

```
python -m pip install --user pymongo
```